# What is the name of the fallacy where acknowledging an issue is confused with actually addressing the issue?

Tags: logic, fallacies

A few days ago an artist came to present his work to our class.

At the beginning of his presentation he said "I know cultural appropriation is a very loaded topic, and it occupies my mind often" as a means to absolve himself from receiving criticism pertaining to cultural appropriation in his own work.

As presented to us, it seemed like he felt that the very act of acknowledging the issue is somehow similar to actually dealing / engaging with it.

I have a sense, though I cannot recall specific examples, that I have seen politicians do this often. They think they are dealing with an issue just by recognizing its existence.

I'm not sure if this fallacy has a name, but if it does, I'm struggling to find it.

I hope my question and description are clear.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why "logic" ???

Comment: I thought that since it's a *logical* fallacy it deserves the "logic" tag, but I'm new to this branch of the Stack Exchange network, so if an admin believes it's the wrong tag, they are welcome to remove it. I won't be offended.

Comment: Sounds similar to [*ignoratio elenchi*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrelevant_conclusion) (Latin for 'ignoring refutation'), presenting  an argument whose conclusion does not address the issue. A simple mention is not exactly an argument, so I am not sure the post's example is a fallacy (mistake in reasoning) rather than a plain misjudgment. And it would only be a mistake (of some sort) if presented as *addressing* an issue, rather than a passing remark in moving on to what one wishes to address instead. That is just being sensitive to the audience's concerns.

Comment: Not everything that people say is an argument, so not everything can be fallacious.

Comment: that's a fair point @curiousdannii thought outside context (which i don't really know) it does read a bit like 'but' can replace 'and'

Comment: It sounds to me that the artist was saying that he was aware of the issue, was sensitive to it, and wanted the class to know that he was doing his best to accommodate its concerns. I do not see a fallacy.